# Cannot speed up compile time in a large project with 20 libraries

Tags: gradle, android-studio-2.1

There is a pretty large Android project that uses approx 20 libraries, both Google's and 3rd party ones. Compiling takes 5min per Gradle Console but in reality it seems it takes more. Maybe this console does not count time needed to resolve some dependencies.

I have a beast i7 machine with 16GB RAM which does not seem to help at all.

I have tried almost any solution from SO that tell how to speed up compiling, but neither helped much.

For example a solution with `--dry-run` will compile it fast if I have not changed anything in the project. Otherwise, it does not help.

The same is with:

gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

which does not seem to help at all.

I have also tried excluding `jcenter()` and leaving only Maven ones, but it did not help at all.

```
mavenLocal()
mavenCentral()
//jcenter()
```

I cannot compile it this way as some libs like `mopub` need `jcenter`.

Is there a solution to my problem? You can image how frustrating it to work on a project where you lose 3rd of a day for compiling.

Comment: Do you have large numbers of dynamic dependencies?  That will definitely chew up time, because Gradle will check for new versions frequently.  You can run with `-i` to get a feel for how much time is being spent pinging for dependencies.

Comment: Hm well there is a ZenDesk plugin and it does contact its website quite a lot. But what's a solution there? An offline mode in Android Studio does not seem to help as well.

Comment: I'm not sure we can talk about solutions until you've identified the true culprit.  For example, have you confirmed that disabling that plugin significantly improves your build-time?

Comment: No, if I disable ZenDesk, then I have to resolve zillions of dependencies in the project. Tried that and deleting all imports seem to take more time that leaving it on. :(

Comment: Is there another way to determine a bottleneck or `-i` is the only way to do it?

Comment: `-i` will give you a much better idea of what Gradle is actually doing second by second (you'd very quickly get an idea of whether it's spending all its time pinging MavenCentral, for example).  I'm sure there's a way you could leverage a standard Java profiler for this, but I've never tried it.

Comment: Have you ever tried a solution to convert repos to local Maven? I wonder if that would speed up compiling? It should IMHO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sad true is that you cannot speed up. But there are a few tricks you can do.

1. Convert remote Maven to the local maven repo. When you run `-i` switch and see that some library is contacting Maven too often and too long, it's a good indicator to convert that library to the local Maven repo.
2. Set `minSdk` to some high value like 19 or 21 (in case `targetSdk` is 23) and compile time will decrease. NOTE: **you can work this way ONLY during debug phase**. Each time you want to make a release APK, you have to compile it the slow way and see if there are any deprecated methods and if you had handled them properly.